# Android File Provider: IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /external/video/media/678

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm tring to get an image from the gallery, but there is something wrong with my File Provider.

On

```
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.pkg.name.fileprovider", result);
```

I get this exception:

```
      11-16 16:57:54.923 24662-24662/com.pkg.name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pkg.name, PID: 24662
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=20, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.pkg.name/com.pkg.name.activities.MainNavigationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /external/video/media/678
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3845)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3888)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1519)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /external/video/media/678
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
        at com.pkg.name.fragments.ChatFragment.sendVideo(ChatFragment.java:620)
        at com.pkg.name.fragments.ChatFragment.access$1600(ChatFragment.java:80)
        at com.pkg.name.fragments.ChatFragment$19.onResult(ChatFragment.java:603)
        at com.pkg.name.fragments.ChatFragment$19.onResult(ChatFragment.java:600)
        at com.pkg.name.controllers.AttachmentPanelController.commitText(AttachmentPanelController.java:214)
        at com.pkg.name.fragments.ChatFragment.commitText(ChatFragment.java:635)
        at com.pkg.name.activities.MainNavigationActivity.onActivityResult(MainNavigationActivity.java:417)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6301)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3841)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3888) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1519) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

And this is my `@xml/file_paths`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="photos" path="Pictures/" />
    <files-path name="videos" path="Videos/" />
    <files-path name="temp" path="temp/" />
    <external-path name="root" path="/" />
</paths>
```

I think that the `root` named path cannot access to the:

```
/external/video/media/
```

because it is on the media reserved storage part.

Comment: Where did you get `result` from? If you got it by calling `getPath()` on a `Uri`, that is where your problem lies.

Comment: It comes from `new File(tempVideo.getPath())` where `Uri tempVideo` comes from a `Intent.ACTION_PICK` intent

Comment: I need to do those casts to pass the value in an Intent Extra as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It comes from new File(tempVideo.getPath()) where Uri tempVideo comes from a Intent.ACTION_PICK intent

A `Uri` is not a file. Calling `getPath()` on a `Uri` only works if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. In your case, the scheme is `content`, in which case `getPath()` is meaningless. And, since there is no requirement that the user pick something that is actually a file, use the `Uri` as it stands. In particular, since you seem to be actively trying to get a `content` `Uri`, recognize that *you already have one*, and try to just use it without modification.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is a good suggestion that helped me to clean a bit my code and to keep it tidy. But how can I pass the Uri to another activity inside an Intent? Do I have to convert it to string?! For example if I want to show the image inside a separate activity to add some details, before I upload it.

Comment: @JackD: Assuming that this other activity is yours, you can use `setData()` or `putExtra()` on the `Intent`. A `Uri` is `Parcelable`, so you do not need to convert it.

Comment: Yes, that's nice. Thank you. Moreover i can use `Uri.toString()` and `Uri.parseUri(String)` to put it in an StringExtra.